# How can I update specific data field by skipping and not filling up other field?

Tags: java, jdbc

Example is this I have to choose

1 Update All

2 Update Individual

When I input 2 this will show

[1]Update Father

[2]Update Mother

[3]Update Brother

[4]Update Sister

When I  choose 2 (update mother) I can only update the mother data,

This is my code, I have 4 scanners. the update all is working but I can't do the individual update on the database.

```
    int id;
    String father, mother, brother, sister;

    System.out.println("Father ");
    Scanner fath = new Scanner(System.in);
    father = fath.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Mother ");
    Scanner moth = new Scanner(System.in);
    mother = moth.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Brother ");
    Scanner bro = new Scanner(System.in);
    brother = bro.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Sister");
    Scanner sis = new Scanner(System.in);
    sister = sis.nextLine();


    sis.close();
    bro.close();
    fath.close();
    moth.close();
```

---

```
PreparedStatement ps = con
                        .prepareStatement("Update family set father = ?, mother = ?, brother = ?, sister = ? where id =?");
            ps.setString(1, father);
            ps.setString(2, mother);
            ps.setString(3, brother);
            ps.setString(4, sister);
            ps.setInt(5, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [IF-THEN-ELSE statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure of your table in the DB.Whether these columns are nullable or not or to be precise what sort of constraints are applied on these columns.

Also, if these columns are nullable in the table then you can use your update query with only one `?` and pass the value you want to insert and execute the same.

For example,

```
con.prepareStatement("Update family set father = ? where id =?");
ps.setString(1, father);
ps.setInt(2, id);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

above query will only update `father` column in the `family` table.

Comment: Should I create another statement for the mother?

like this?

`con.prepareStatement("Update family set father = ? where id =?");

ps.setString(1, father);

ps.setInt(2, id);
ps.executeUpdate();

con.prepareStatement("Update family set mother= ? where id =?");
ps.setString(1, mother);
ps.setInt(2, id);
ps.executeUpdate();`

Comment: The thing is you need the id(assuming PK here) to update the row in `family` table. If that `id` exist int the table then you can update any of the column in whatever fashion you want i.e, it could be one at a time or more than one also.

Comment: And, to answer your question - Yes, you would need to run another query(one which you have shared in the comments) in order to update `mother` column value in the `family` table.

Answer (score 0):

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Update family set father = ?,where id =?");
            ps.setString(1, father);
            ps.setInt(2, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();